# Hanging after establishing SSH connection

Tags: ssh, azure

### Prolog

I was working on my Ubuntu VM (running on Azure) when I was suddenly disconnected last night. I had not scheduled any restart myself, so I am not sure what could have caused this. I was logged in and actively working, and did nothing like apt-get upgrade or similar at that moment.

### Problem

After being disconnected I have been able to connect, just not complete the login.

Any clues to what can cause this and how to fix it?

### ssh output

```
$ ssh -v myuser@myapp.cloudapp.net
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to myapp.cloudapp.net [137.116.246.159] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/oligofren/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/oligofren/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/oligofren/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/oligofren/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
```

At this point nothing happens. It just hangs there doing nothing - not quitting, not doing anything else.

Comment: Also posted on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/c2b7366a-ae61-45aa-9794-6dd9ed5b0169/suddenly-lost-ssh-access-to-ubuntu-1404-lts-vm?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows#c2b7366a-ae61-45aa-9794-6dd9ed5b0169

Comment: Do you have any other access to the server? Can you restart it ?

Comment: did you make a snapshot of your server? I would halt the instance and start up from a previous snapshot. Highly likely is that your instance ran out of disk space.

Comment: Do you have webmin or a c-panel like web administration utility installed? That would be your next best hope. Did have Xrdp or VNC running on it? Those are unlikely but possible.

Comment: Seems Azure crashed on me. A hard reboot fixed things. No idea what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure instance seemed to have crashed/frozen.

At least that's my diagnosis after coming back to work on Monday morning and trying to reboot it. It was saying it was shutting down the VM for at least an hour before it completed.

After rebooting the Azure instance everything worked again.